# Calendar size too small in Tkcalendar

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, calendar

I am making an attendance system in Tkinter. And I came across Tkcalendar but the calendar size seems small. Is there any way to increase the size of the calendar? Or do I have to make a custom calendar? Any help will be appreciated.

[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDPuK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: https://tkcalendar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/example.html
for code examples demonstrating the calendar. Here the first one:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkcalendar import Calendar
root = Tk()
root.geometry('920x640')
cal = Calendar(root, font="Arial 14", selectmode='day', locale='en_US',
               cursor="hand1", year=2021, month=6, day=19)
cal.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

If 920x640 is still to small change it to 1024x768 or 1280x920 . Anyway, the calendar has not a fixed size and resizes to the chosen window size. If you need larger numbers, increase the font size to e.g. 24 in `Calendar(root, font="Arial 24"`. No need to write an own version or patch the module.